# How to reverse an array of strings without changing the position of special characters in C#

Tags: c#

I'm working on reversing a sentence. I'm able to do it. But I'm not sure, how to reverse the word without changing the special characters positions. I'm using regex but as soon as it finds the special characters it's stopping the reversal of the word.

Following is the code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter:");
string w = Console.ReadLine();   
string rw = String.Empty;
String[] arr = w.Split(' ');
var regexItem = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
StringBuilder appendString = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    char[] chararray = arr[i].ToCharArray();
    for (int j = chararray.Length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {

     if (regexItem.IsMatch(rw))
{
    rw = appendString.Append(chararray[j]).ToString();
}
    }
    sb.Append(' ');
}              
Console.WriteLine(rw);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Example : Input

> Marshall! Hello.

Expected output

> llahsram! olleh.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what to do if a string contains both special and non-special characters. What should be the output for `"apple.boo?charlie"`?

Comment: Could you give some examples of what you are attempting?

Comment: in my code it is reversing correctly but it gives output as !llahsram .olleh, whereas it is also reversing the position of special character

Comment: special characters could be abnything like this "!@#$%^&*()<>?/.,{}[]"

Comment: @Dan Yeah. that's correct..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A basic solution with regex and LINQ. [Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/86qPmf).

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Marshall! Hello.");
    Console.WriteLine(Reverse("Marshall! Hello."));
}

public static string Reverse(string source)
{
    // we split by groups to keep delimiters
    var parts = Regex.Split(source, @"([^a-zA-Z0-9])");
    // if we got a group of valid characters
    var results = parts.Select(x => x.All(char.IsLetterOrDigit)
            // we reverse it
            ? new string(x.Reverse().ToArray())
            // or we keep the delimiters as it
            : x);
    // then we concat all of them
    return string.Concat(results);
}
```

---

The same solution without LINQ. [Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TQNHox).

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Marshall! Hello.");
    Console.WriteLine(Reverse("Marshall! Hello."));

}

public static bool IsLettersOrDigits(string s)
{
    foreach (var c in s)
    {
        if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static string Reverse(char[] s)
{
    Array.Reverse(s);
    return new string(s);
}


public static string Reverse(string source)
{
    var parts = Regex.Split(source, @"([^a-zA-Z0-9])");

    var results = new List<string>();
    foreach(var x in parts)
    {
        results.Add(IsLettersOrDigits(x)
                   ? Reverse(x.ToCharArray())
                   : x);
    }
    return string.Concat(results);
}
```

Comment: @Marshall you can but the code will be far more longer.

Comment: @Ðаn Like (\W)? it would allow _. I am not sure OP want this.

Comment: I apologize if the question is misguiding. I was thinking from my prespective. Please, let me know if i need to update the question. Because if you look at the answer posted by Selman Genc. That is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @Ðаn I agree. More examples would be helpful. I kept the regex as go to usecase.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. I would update the question. But As of now the answer posted by aloisdg and selamn both works absolutely fine for me

Comment: @Marshall glad to be helpful, but as Dan said, be careful about special case. :)

Comment: Yes, that is true I agree, but I used most of the frequently used special characters. So, it is working for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution without LINQ. I wasn't sure about what are considered special characters.

```
        string sentence = "Marshall! Hello.";
        List<string> words = sentence.Split(' ').ToList();
        List<string> reversedWords = new List<string>();

        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            char[] arr = new char[word.Length];

            for( int i=0; i<word.Length; i++)
            {
                if(!Char.IsLetterOrDigit((word[i])))
                {
                    for ( int x=0; x< i; x++)
                    {
                        arr[x] = arr[x + 1];
                    }
                    arr[i] = word[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    arr[word.Length - 1 - i] = word[i];
                }
            }

            reversedWords.Add(new string(arr));
        }

        string reversedSentence = string.Join(" ", reversedWords);

        Console.WriteLine(reversedSentence);
```

And this is the output:

```
   Updated Output = llahsraM! olleH.
```

Comment: You dont need to convert words to a List. In fact, you dont need it at all.

Comment: I appreciate your time. Butt your code changes the position of "."

Comment: Add that to the list of special characters and you should be good.

Comment: how to check for all the available special characters rather than giving a list.

Comment: If you just want digits or letters you can try to change if (specials.Contains(word[i])) with Char.IsLetterOrDigit(word[i])

Comment: This is great work. Thanks for the update! Very optimized version.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-regex version that does what you want:

```
var sentence = "Hello, john!";
var parts = sentence.Split(' ');
var reversed = new StringBuilder();
var charPositions = sentence.Select((c, idx) => new { Char = c, Index = idx })
                            .Where(_ => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(_.Char));

for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
{
     var chars = parts[i].ToCharArray();

     for (int j = chars.Length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
     {
         if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(chars[j]))
         {
            reversed.Append(chars[j]);
         }
     }
}

foreach (var ch in charPositions)
{
    reversed.Insert(ch.Index, ch.Char);
}

// olleH, nhoj!
Console.WriteLine(reversed.ToString());
```

Basically the trick is to remember the position of special (i.e. non letter or digit) characters and insert them at the end to those positions.

Comment: Is there a way where I can do without using Linq!

Comment: Nothing wrong in it! Wanted to know if there is a way to do without linq. This works for me but was curious to know

Answer (score -1):

This solution is without LINQ and Regex. It may not be an efficient answer but working properly for small string values.

```
    // This will reverse the string and special characters will just stay there.
    public string ReverseString(string rString)
    {
        StringBuilder ss = new StringBuilder(rString);
        int y = 0;
        // The idea is to swap values. Like swapping first value with last one. It will keep swapping unless it reaches at the middle of the string where no swapping will be needed.
        // This first loop is to detect first values.
        for(int i=rString.Length-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            // This condition is to check if the values is String or not. If it is not string then it is considered as special character which will just stay there at same old position.
            if(Char.IsLetter(Convert.ToChar(rString.Substring(i,1))))
            {          
                // This is second loop which is starting from end to swap values from end with first.         
                for (int k = y; k < rString.Length; k++)
                {
                    // Again checking last values if values are string or not. 
                    if (Char.IsLetter(Convert.ToChar(rString.Substring(k, 1))))
                    {
                        // This is swapping. So st1 is First value in that string
                        // st2 is the last item in that string
                        char st1 = Convert.ToChar(rString.Substring(k, 1));
                        char st2 = Convert.ToChar(rString.Substring(i, 1));

                        //This is swapping. So last item will go to first position and first item will go to last position, To make sure string is reversed.
                        // Remember when the string value is Special Character, swapping will move forward without swapping.
                        ss[rString.IndexOf(rString.Substring(i, 1))] = st1;
                        ss[rString.IndexOf(rString.Substring(k, 1))] = st2;
                        y++;
                        // When the swapping is done for first 2 items. The loop will stop to change the values.
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // This is just increment if value was Special character. 
                        y++;
                    }
                }                    
            }
        }

        return ss.ToString();
    }
```

Thanks!